# Check column value

Tags: 2010, column, library, unique

Is it possible to check a column in a library for unique or rather similar values?
We have a librabry and it is very important to detect duplicate documents. We uncheck the overwrite checkbox, but if the user make a mistake by typing the name with a blank, the document will be uploaded normally.
Has somebody an idea to handle this "problem"?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is just like Windows file system, so it allows document with same name to be in different folders in same document library.

The below powershell script will finds duplicate files based on document contents rather than document names.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
function Get-DuplicateFiles ($RootSiteUrl)
{
$spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity $RootSiteUrl
$Items = @()
foreach ($SPweb in $spSite.allwebs)
{
Write-Host “Checking ” $spWeb.Title ” for duplicate documents”
foreach ($list in $spWeb.Lists)
{
if($list.BaseType -eq “DocumentLibrary” -and $list.RootFolder.Url -notlike “_*” -and   $list.RootFolder.Url -notlike “SitePages*”)
{
foreach($item in $list.Items)
{
$record = New-Object -TypeName System.Object
if($item.File.length -gt 0)
{
$fileArray = $item.File.OpenBinary()
$hash = Get-MD5($fileArray)
$record | Add-Member NoteProperty ContentHash ($hash)
$record | Add-Member NoteProperty FileName ($file.Name)
$record | Add-Member NoteProperty FullPath ($spWeb.Url + “/” + $item.Url)
$Items += $record
}
}
}
}
$spWeb.Dispose()
$duplicateHashes = $Items | Group-Object ContentHash | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1}
foreach($duplicatehash in $duplicateHashes)
{
$duplicateFiles += $Items | Where-Object{$_.contentHash -eq $duplicatehash.Name}
$duplicateFiles += “————————————————————”
}
    }
    return $duplicateFiles |Format-Table FullPath
    }
    function Get-MD5($file = $(throw ‘Usage:Get-MD5[System.IO.FileInfo]‘))
    {
    $stream = $null;
    $cryptoServiceProvider = [System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider];
    $hasAlgorithm = New-Object $cryptoServiceProvider
    $stream = $file;
    $hashByteArray = $hasAlgorithm.ComputeHash($stream);
    return [string]$hashByteArray;
    }
    Get-DuplicateFiles(<your sharepoint site>)
```

Change the above code accoirding to your need.

**Or**

you can try with writing event receivers to check the Titles before adding\updating the documents .

hope this helps you.

[Power Shell Script source](http://blog.pointbeyond.com/2011/08/24/finding-duplicate-documents-in-sharepoint-using-powershell/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have one short question. Should i be server administrator to use the script? Because i'm only administrator for sharepoint online. I can't run powershell as admin.

Comment: Which version of sharepoint are you using.?

Comment: 2010 standard version

Comment: I havent worked in SharePoint online, so I'm not sure about it, have a try with it and let us know. :)

Comment: I tested it, but i get no connection to SharePoint. In spite of everything thank you very much for your help.
Maybe i'll find a way with a javascript